# Install packages from LTS Hardware Enablement Stack for Ubuntu 14.04.3 has unmet dependancies

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

I was able to install the new kernel,3.19, however, when I try to get the new packages for the hardware enablement stack  and attempt this command

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

terminal output:

```
     linux-generic-lts-vivid is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcogl15 : Depends: libegl1-mesa-drivers
 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid : Depends: libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid (= 10.5.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                                  Conflicts: xorg-renamed-package-lts-utopic
 xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid : Depends: libgbm1-lts-vivid (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid (>= 7.10.2-4) but it is not going to be installed
                               Conflicts: xorg-renamed-package-lts-utopic
 xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-lts-vivid : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-vivid but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libgbm1-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                          Conflicts: libegl1-mesa (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: libgles2-mesa (>= 0~)
                          Conflicts: xorg-renamed-package-lts-utopic
 xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.ode
```

It says that I cannot download because of a series of unmet dependencies. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the whole terminal output?

Comment: @xangua I added the terminal output to the post/

Comment: I have got the same issue. Just filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1483631

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` ?